# Explanation on Inference Time

Tags: niftynet

Can anyone explain to me why the first window in inference takes considerably longer time compared to following windows when input data is larger than window size?
Here's ans example of execution times for my application:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEJ67.png)